# Can't login from GDM

Tags: gnome, login, gdm

I've upgraded to Gnome on my Ubuntu desktop, however I have to login in with tty and run `startx`, but when the computer sleeps, I have the gnome login screen and it doesn't accept my tty password... There is only one user and one password...

Is there a default password I can use?

Comment: Try changing the keyboard layouts. It should accept you user's TTY password, there is no default password as that would be pointless from a security point of view - the screen you see after suspend is probably the lock screen, which you *could* disable from Power & Privacy settings/uninstalling gnome-screensaver in old version of Gnome.

Comment: I've tried disabling the lock screen using gnome extension caffeine it works but when I close my laptop for hibernation it doesn't accept my tty password which is only one basic letter!ni can't edit the privacy settings the button won't toggle its greyed out

Comment: Did you ever fix your issue? If so, please post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is no, there is no default password.

However, it sounds like your keyboard settings for X differ from those settings for tty. Are you using a non-US keyboard, i.e. an AZERTY keyboard from example, or numbers in your password on a French keyboard? There are a couple of things you can try:

- Look at the log files to see what the errors are being thrown up,
  when you try to log in to the GNOME login;
- Change your password to something where the keys are always the same
  on any keyboard layout, for example `uiopkj`;
- Copy your `.xinitrc` file to `.xinitrc.bak`, and delete all the lines in the original `.xinitrc` file. Run `startx` with the empty `.xinitrc` file. Now try to test your keyboard layout setup.

You probably just need to ensure that the keyboard layouts in tty and Xorg are the same. I've had this happen to me many a time, when I was a locale test engineer, using loads of different "foreign" keyboards. Most frustrating.

Comment: Shoot! Only just seen Wilf's comment. Sorry...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer guys I'm not using a foreign keyboard and my password is only one letter..

Comment: Hmmm... That is most odd... You've got me stumped. If you find out what the issue is, I'd like to know the answer. Good luck :-)

Comment: @Beginner - having a one letter password is not a bright idea (telling the internet does not help as well). You can change your password a few times using `passwd` or user settings and see if any others work. It may be that GDM can't process very very short passwords or something like that. Some settings may not work properly unless started from logging in to GDM, so find a password that works with GDM first.